# I cant access the desired attribute of the object in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, hotchocolate

I am trying to implement Authorization in my .Net Core web api and after setting up my program.cs and after "decorating" the desired method with the `[Authorize("ArchiveList")]` I am having problems with handling the request in my HandleRequirement method.

[image: Here's the example of the object I get when I try to execute a method with the [Authorize] attribute on top of it.]

I want to be able to access the name of the method that is making the request, and that is in the `context.Resource` -> Field but when I try to read `context.Resource` it only gives me the string "HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.MiddlewareContext` which is not what I really need/want.
I can share the program.cs authorization coding part if needed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry i am sure what do you mean about `I want to be able to access the name of the method that is making the request`, Do you want to get the name of method which the current request access to?

Comment: Hi @XinranShen, I mean I want to get the name of the method (with the [Attribute] notations on top) that is trying to making a request which triggers this `HandleRequirementAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get the name of the action with [Authorize] attribute in `HandleRequirementAsync` method, you can use below code to achieve it.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SingleBuildingPolicyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var endpoint = context.Resource as HttpContext;

        if (endpoint != null) {
            var actioname = endpoint.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
        }
        //........
}
```

[image]